# JSP form submit and list population issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I'm having a couple issues with a simple JSP app.  When I go to the Add or Delete pages, I'm able to input data and submit it, the item is either added or deleted to/from the database as it is supposed to be, but instead of returning me to the page, it sends me to a page that says, "Served at: /ToDoList".  I can use the back button to return to the page, but it is supposed to simply reload the same jsp page.  It worked previously, but I'm not sure what I changed.

Additionally, I'm trying to populate a table with the data from a database on the Show List page (show.jsp), but it gives me a ConcurrentModificationException that I can't figure out.  I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any help is appreciated.  The ListItem object is just an int itemID and string itemDesc.  Code follows:

add.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add an item</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add an item</h1>
<form action="AddItem" method="post">
 <table>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="desc" value="" size="100"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="addSub" /></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="Back to menu" onclick="window.location='/ToDoList/index.jsp'">
</body>
</html>
```

delete.jsp

```html
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show list</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<form action="ShowList" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Populate">
</form>
 <table>
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${dispList}">
     <tr>
      <td>${item.itemID}</td>
      <td>${item.itemDesc}.</td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>
 </table>
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="Back to menu" onclick="window.location='/ToDoList/index.jsp'">
</body>
</html>
```

show.jsp

```html
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show list</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<form action="ShowList" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Populate">
</form>
 <table>
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${dispList}">
     <tr>
      <td>${item.itemID}</td>
      <td>${item.itemDesc}.</td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>
 </table>
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="Back to menu" onclick="window.location='/ToDoList/index.jsp'">
</body>
</html>
```

ItemList.java

```html
package todolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

public class ItemList {
 List<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
 List<ListItem> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

 public static SessionFactory factory;
 
 public ItemList() {
  super();
 }

 public void addItem(String itemStr) {  
  //list.add(item);
  //list.get(list.size() - 1).setItemNumber(list.size());
  ListItem item = new ListItem(itemStr);
  try {
   factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  } catch (Throwable ex) { 
   System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
  }
  Session session = factory.openSession();
     Transaction tx = null;
     Integer itemID = null;
     try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        itemID = (Integer) session.save(item);
     tx.commit();
     } catch (HibernateException e) {
      if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
      e.printStackTrace(); 
  } finally {
   session.close(); 
  }
 }
 
 public void delItem(int itemNbr) {
  try {
   factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  } catch (Throwable ex) { 
   System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
  }
     Session session = factory.openSession();  
     Transaction tx = null;
     ListItem item2 = (ListItem)session.get(ListItem.class, itemNbr);
     try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(item2); 
        tx.commit();
     } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
     } finally {
        session.close(); 
     }
 }
 
 public List<ListItem> getList() {
  try {
   factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  } catch (Throwable ex) { 
   System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
  }
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
     try {
       tx = session.beginTransaction();
       Query<ListItem> queryList = session.createQuery("FROM itemlist");
       tempList = queryList.list();
       tx.commit();   
       } catch (HibernateException e) {
          if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
          e.printStackTrace(); 
       } finally {
          session.close(); 
       }
     list = tempList;
     return list;
 }
 
 public int size() {
  return list.size();
 }
}
```

AddItem.java

```html
package todolist;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddItem
 */
@WebServlet("/AddItem")
public class AddItem extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 ItemList list = new ItemList();
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddItem() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("add.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response); 
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  if(request.getParameter("desc")!=null) {
   String desc = request.getParameter("desc");
   list.addItem(desc);
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("add.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
  }
  
 }

}
```

DelItem.java

```html
package todolist;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DelItem
 */
@WebServlet("/DelItem")
public class DelItem extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 ItemList list = new ItemList();       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DelItem() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("delete.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  if(request.getParameter("itemNbr")!=null && request.getParameter("itemNbr")!="") {
   int itemNbr = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("itemNbr"));
   list.delItem(itemNbr);
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("delete.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
  }

 }

}
```

ShowList.java

```html
package todolist;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ShowList
 */
@WebServlet("/ShowList")
public class ShowList extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 ItemList list2 = new ItemList();
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ShowList() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("show.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  List<ListItem> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
  tempList = list2.getList();
  request.setAttribute("dispList", tempList);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("show.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
 }

}
```